# in execl minimum limit of raw and columan

Tags: excel

Respected Sir/Madam

I want to key 60 records in first sheet, and 61th records key on next sheet. I want after
60 records cursur is go to automaticully 61th records.
means after every 60th records curuser is going to next sheet.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

From your question I think you need to use the `SelectionChange` event to detect when a cell on any row >60 is selected.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
    If target.Row > 60 Then
        Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

This code would need to be placed in each worksheet code module that you wanted the automatic jump to the next worksheet to happen in.  It makes the following assumptions:

- It fires any time a cell with row number >60 is selected
- It just increments the worksheet index to get the next sheet
- It assumes your data starts in cell A1

This should allow you to get started though.

Answer (score 0):

With some presto code I would say the logic would be something like this

```
If ActiveSheet=”Sheet1” AND ActiveRow>=61 then 
    ActiveSheet=”Sheet2”
End if
```

I’m sorry that I’m not at a computer with office installed so cant generate the actual code but I think you see where I’m going with this